# How to keep websockets listening as a background service?

Tags: java, android, websocket, socket.io

I have a service to handle my websocket events however it stops listening when the UI is closed - however, I can still emit messages (eg. location data). How do I keep websockets running in the background so it will listen for events on boot or when the main UI thread is closed?

```
public class HomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
    public static final String TAG = HomeActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    public static final String PREFS_NAME = "MyPrefsFile";
    String userName = "init";
    String token = "init";
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
        WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
        WifiInfo wInfo = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo();
        String macAddress = wInfo.getMacAddress();
        TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtMac);
        textView.setText(macAddress);

        startService(new Intent(getBaseContext(), wsService.class));

        SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
        userName = settings.getString("username","does not exist");
        token = settings.getString("token","does not exist");
        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtEmail);
        textView.setText(userName);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Beacon");

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    }


    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.home, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.nav_camera) {
            // Handle the camera action
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_slideshow) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_logout) {
            Log.i(TAG, "<<<<---- LOGOUT ---->>> ");
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), HomeActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }


        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }
}
```

This is the service being started from the activity above:

```
public class wsService extends Service implements OnPreparedListener {
    public static final String PREFS_NAME = "MyPrefsFile";
    double longitude = 0;
    double latitude = 0;
    long time = 0;
    float speed = 0;
    float accuracy = 0;
    float bearing = 0;
    boolean sound_stopped = true;
    String userName = "init";
    String token = "init";
    public static final String TAG = wsService.class.getSimpleName();
    private LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
    MediaPlayer mp;

    /** indicates how to behave if the service is killed */
    int mStartMode;

    /** interface for clients that bind */
    IBinder mBinder;

    /** indicates whether onRebind should be used */
    boolean mAllowRebind;
    private Socket mSocket;
    {
        try {
            mSocket = IO.socket("http://192.168.0.2:5000");
        } catch (URISyntaxException e) {}

    }

    /** Called when the service is being created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        Log.d(TAG, "-- Starting wsService --");
        new LongOperation().execute("test");
        mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.led);
        String locationProvider = LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER;
        mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create() // Create the LocationRequest object
                .setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY)
                .setInterval(10 * 1000)        // 10 seconds, in milliseconds
                .setFastestInterval(1 * 1000); // 1 second, in milliseconds
        // Acquire a reference to the system Location Manager
        LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(locationProvider, 0, 0, locationListener);
    }

    private class LongOperation extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            Log.d(TAG, "-- Starting BACKGROUND wsService --");
            mSocket.connect();
            mSocket.on("to_mobile", onCommand);
            return "Executed";
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {}

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {}
    }

    //Listening new message event to receive message
    private Emitter.Listener onCommand = new Emitter.Listener() {
        @Override
        public void call(final Object... args) {
            JSONObject data = (JSONObject)args[0];
            String command = null;
            try {
                command = data.getString("command");
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            Log.i(TAG, "<<<<---- RECEIVING COMMAND ----->>> " + command);
            if (command.equals("ping_audio_start")) {
                start_sound();
            }
            if (command.equals("ping_audio_stop")) {
                stop_sound();
            }
            if (command.equals("ping_gps")) {
                Log.i(TAG, "<<<<---- RESPONDING GPS REQUEST ----->>> ");
                mSocket.emit("from_mobile", gps_string);
            }

        }
    };

    String gps_string = "HELLO FROM DROID";
    private void handleNewLocation(Location location) {
        WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
        WifiInfo wInfo = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo();
        String macAddress = wInfo.getMacAddress();
        longitude = location.getLongitude();
        latitude = location.getLatitude();
        time = location.getTime();
        speed = location.getSpeed();
        accuracy = location.getAccuracy();
        bearing = location.getBearing();
        SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
        userName = settings.getString("username","does not exist");
        token = settings.getString("token","does not exist");
        gps_string = "{ \"mac\":\"" + macAddress
                + "\", \"userName\":\"" + userName
                + "\", \"token\":\"" + token
                + "\", \"time\":\"" + time
                + "\", \"longitude\":\"" + longitude
                + "\", \"latitude\":\"" + latitude
                + "\", \"speed\":\"" + speed
                + "\", \"accuracy\":\"" + accuracy
                + "\", \"bearing\":\"" + bearing
                + "\"}";
        mSocket.emit("from_mobile", gps_string);
        Log.i(TAG, "<<<<---- SENDING GPS DATA ---->>> ");
    }

    // Define a listener that responds to location updates
    LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            handleNewLocation(location);
        }
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {}

        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {}

        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {}
    };

    public void start_sound() {
        Log.i(TAG, "<<<<---- START PING ----->>>");
        mp.release();
        mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.led);
        mp.setLooping(true);
        mp.start();
        mp.setVolume(1, 1);
        sound_stopped = false;

    }
    public void stop_sound() {
        Log.i(TAG, "<<<<---- STOP PING ----->>> ");
        mp.stop();
        sound_stopped = true;
    }

    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer player) {
        player.start();
    }
        /** The service is starting, due to a call to startService() */
    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        return mStartMode;
    }

    /** A client is binding to the service with bindService() */
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return mBinder;
    }

    /** Called when all clients have unbound with unbindService() */
    @Override
    public boolean onUnbind(Intent intent) {
        return mAllowRebind;
    }

    /** Called when a client is binding to the service with bindService()*/
    @Override
    public void onRebind(Intent intent) {

    }

    /** Called when The service is no longer used and is being destroyed */
    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

IntentService is running only for as long as the it needs to handle the Intent. i.e if there are no intents left to process, the service closes automatically.

Try a normal service instead.

Comment: I got the same results...I can receive messages until UI is closed. I can still emit messages (eg location data).

Comment: A service is not dependent on a UI so something in your implementation is wrong. Try reading the documentation to see where you are going wrong. http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html As you have posted no UI code, it is impossible to tell what you are doing incorrectly. Perhaps you are simply stopping the service instead of allowing it to continue running.

Comment: Okay, yes I've read that but I'm still not sure why it's being stopped. I will add the UI code above

Comment: added...I'm starting the service using startService(new Intent(getBaseContext(), wsService.class));